# Xcode: Read text file from URL

Tags: xcode

I'm new to Xcode. I have the following code working perfectly to read a text file located in the project bundle.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *textFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

My question is how to read the text file from URL?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit more involved than reading a file. Use the [`NURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) class.

Comment: I did provide a link. Clicking on the class name will take you to a fairly comprehensive guide.

Answer (score 0):

### I Found a Way to Read the File By Doing This:

```
let str = "Text Here"
let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("file.txt")
do {
    try str?.write(to: filename, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
}catch {
    print("Something Went Wrong")
}
```